# FindControl GridTemplateColumn Outside of radGrid Events with out using foreach statement

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Find Control of  `Grid Template Column` Outside of RadGrid Events with out using for each statement.
I am using for each means all the value inserted .I will insert particular row Only.Please refer  my code

```
 protected void txtRemarks_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HMS.model.PatientQueue objPatient = new model.PatientQueue();
            foreach (GridItem item in gvStudents.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
              if (item is GridItem)
             {
          //  GridItem cmdItem = gvStudents.MasterTableView.Items;

                   GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)item;
                    TextBox txtRemark = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtRemarks");

                   // TextBox txtRemark = (TextBox)this.gvStudents.FindControl("txtRemarks");
                    objPatient.Remarks = txtRemark.Text;
                    if (txtRemark.Text != "")
                    {
                        objPatient.UID = _common.Utility.ToString(this.gvStudents.MasterTableView.Items[dataItem.ItemIndex].GetDataKeyValue("UID"));

                        int returnval = objPatient.InsertRemarks();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```